# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') at Category i am getting this error please help me to solve it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, api, strapi

when i do not map any data in Category.jsx it works fine as soon as i try to grab data from strapi api and write following code in Category.jsx i got UncoughtTypeError in my consol.

Home.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";

import "./Home.scss";

import Banner from './Banner/Banner'
import Category from "./Category/Category";
import Products from "../Products/Products";
import { fetchDataFromApi } from "../../utils/api";
import { Context } from "../../utils/context";

const Home = () => {
    const { categories, setCategories, products, setProducts } = useContext(Context);
    useEffect(() => {
        getProducts();
        getCategories();
    }, []);

    const getProducts = () => {
        fetchDataFromApi("/api/products?populate=*").then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            setProducts(res)
        });
    }

    const getCategories = () => {
        fetchDataFromApi("/api/categories?populate=*").then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            setCategories(res)
        });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Banner />
            <div className="main-content">
                <div className="layout">
                    <Category categories={categories} />
                    <Products products={products} headingText="Popular Products" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Category.jsx

```
import "./Category.scss";

import cat1 from '../../../assets/category/cat1.jpg'

const Category = ({categories}) => {
    return (
        <div className="shop-by-category">
            <div className="categories">
                {categories.data.map((item) => {
                    <div key={item.id} className="category">
                        <img src={process.env.REACT_APP_STORE_URL + item.attributes.img.data.attributes.url} 
                        alt="" />
                    </div> 
                })}        
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Category;
```

context.jsx

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const Context = createContext();

const AppContext = ({ children }) => {
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState()
    const [products, setProducts] = useState()
    return (
        <Context.Provider
            value={{
                categories,
                setCategories,
                products,
                setProducts
            }}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    );
}

export default AppContext;
```

api.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const params = {
    headers: {
        Authorization: "bearer" + process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_APP_KEY
    }
}

export const fetchDataFromApi = async (url) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(process.env.REACT_APP_STORE_URL + url, params)
        return data
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return error
    }
}
```

As this is my first project i am not very comfortable with it, looking for easy and better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the value of `categories.data` before `map`. And conditionally display a failure message.

Also included `return ( ... )` inside your loop

```
const Category = ({categories}) => {
  return (
    <div className="shop-by-category">
      <div className="categories">
        {
          categories && categories.data ? 
          categories.data.map((item) => { 
            return (
              <div key={item.id} className="category">
                {item.id}
                <img src={process.env.REACT_APP_STORE_URL + item.attributes.img.data.attributes.url} alt="" />
              </div>
            )
          }) : (
            <div>No categories</div>
          )
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: `import "./Products.scss";
import Product from '../Products/Product/Product'
const Products = ({ products, innerPage, headingText }) => {
  return (
    <div className="products-container">
      {!innerPage && <div className="sec-heading">{headingText}</div>}
      <div className="product">
        {products.data.map(item => (
          <Product key={item.id} id={item.id} data={item.attributes} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Products;`    can you tell me why i am getting Uncaught TypeError in console after this code

Comment: @CommonAccount can you share the full error?

Comment: here's link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75759060/not-getting-data-from-strapi-api-properly?noredirect=1#comment133644433_75759060

Comment: thanks @CommonAccount. moving discussion to the other question.