# Not getting data from strapi api properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, strapi

I am trying to get data from strapi api and when i am trying to get data of products i ended up with only getting products number how i can get all the products with price and title of products below necessory files are atteched.

Home.jsx

```
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";

import "./Home.scss";

import Banner from './Banner/Banner'
import Category from "./Category/Category";
import Products from "../Products/Products";
import { fetchDataFromApi } from "../../utils/api";
import { Context } from "../../utils/context";

const Home = () => {
    const { categories, setCategories, products, setProducts } = useContext(Context);
    useEffect(() => {
        getProducts();
        getCategories();
    }, []);

    const getProducts = () => {
        fetchDataFromApi("/api/products?populate=*").then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            setProducts(res)
        });
    }

    const getCategories = () => {
        fetchDataFromApi("/api/categories?populate=*").then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            setCategories(res)
        });
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Banner />
            <div className="main-content">
                <div className="layout">
                    <Category categories={categories} />
                    <Products products={products} headingText="Popular Products" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Products.jsx

```
import "./Products.scss";

import Product from '../Products/Product/Product'

const Products = ({ products, innerPage, headingText }) => {
    return (
        <div className="products-container">
            {!innerPage && <div className="sec-heading">{headingText}</div>}
            <div className="product">
            {
            products && products.data ? 
            products.data.map((item) => { 
              return (
                <div key={item.id} id={item.id} className="category">
                  {item.id}
                  <img src={process.env.REACT_APP_STORE_URL + item.attributes} alt="" />
                </div>
              )
            }) : (
              <div>No products</div>
            )
          }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Products;
```

Product.jsx

```
import "./Product.scss";
import prod from '../../../assets/products/sneakers-prod-1.png'
const Product = ({id,data}) => {
    return <div className="product-card">
        <div className="thumbnail">
            <img src={prod} alt="" />
        </div>
        <div className="prod-details">
            <span className="name">Dress shoe Taobao Leather Footwear</span>
            <span className="price">&#8377;499</span>
        </div>
    </div>;
};

export default Product;
```

Context.js

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const Context = createContext();

const AppContext = ({ children }) => {
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState()
    const [products, setProducts] = useState()
    return (
        <Context.Provider
            value={{
                categories,
                setCategories,
                products,
                setProducts
            }}>
            {children}
        </Context.Provider>
    );
}

export default AppContext;
```

i was expecting to get products which i've uploaded on strapi api but all i am getting is product number

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @CommonAccount in `Products.jsx` you're looping through products and printing out each id. Your imported `Product` is not in use anywhere, it should be used inside the loop. Is that the issue?

Comment: no, the issue was i was trying printing each elements from strapi and one image was missing from one field now the issue has been solved. btw thanks